# datetime difference shows wrong values in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, difference

In my website I show some data according to the date it added to the database. It will place a tag "NEW" to the product which added with in last 7 days. The code works perfectly till today. Now it shows wrong values. I am using the below code to get the difference

```
DATE(stored_date_time) - DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS days
```

and the output of this code is `77`. But today date is `2014-07-01`

while echoing the value of `DATE(stored_date_time)` it gives the output

```
2014-07-01
```

and echoing of `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)` gives the output

```
2014-06-24
```

I cant find what is wrong with my code. Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subtracting those date, it would be better if you use `DATEDIFF`, like below:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2008-06-05','2008-08-05') AS DiffDate
```

which will return 61.. for more info [func_datediff](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Arun, 
Since you asked what is wrong with your code.

```
select date1 - date2 as days;
```

It is not actually meaningful at all. The values of dates in number format
are just formed as "yyyymmddhhmmss". So it contains the same information
as the string, but instead of using characters, each digit is actually
an integer. That format might be useful for someone, but you can't use
that format to calculate differences.

Basically what i am trying to say is, if the query above is run for say 
'2014-07-02' and '2014-06-22' you'll get 80 as result. Which is in fact

```
20140702-20140622 =80.
```

So like you have already been adviced on the other post, use the datediff() function.

Comment: thanks a lot... now its clear what is happening... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DATE(stored_date_time),DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AS days
```

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered similar issue. I was using `CAST((1000000 * (moment2 - moment1)) as UNSIGNED)`, where moment1 and moment2 are DATETIME(6). And it was working perfectly until once I got enormous value for one of thousands values. What is ridiculous, why it was working all the time, and only one pair of values gave invalid result. Now changed request to `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, moment1, moment2)`, it works OK.